# Notice: ... Unknown on line 0 - How to find correct line, it's NOT "line 0"

Tags: php

Edit: added the PDO call.

This is the actual error:

```
Notice: Object of class PDOStatement could not be converted to int in Unknown on line 0
```

How can I in general find out which line is the correct line of the error/notice, since it is **NOT** `line 0`?

I tried using register_tick_function echoing out **file:line**, which does not work, because the notice is always outputted at the end of my total output.

I am looking for a general debugging way, since I could not find any error in my class of that object.

```
// PHP PDO Standard
$db_server = 'mysql:host='.$this->db_host.';dbname='.$this->db_dbase;
try {
  $this->db_connection = new PDO($db_server, $this->db_user, $this->db_pass);
  $pdo_set = $this->db_connection->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES, FALSE);
  $pdo_set = $this->db_connection->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
  $pdo_set = $this->db_connection->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_DEFAULT_FETCH_MODE, PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
  //DebugPrint($pdo_set, '$pdo_set');
} catch (PDOException $e) {
  //print 'Error!: '.$e->getMessage().'<br/>';
  die();
}
```

Comment: Check your php.ini for auto_prepend_file

Comment: Just look for the lines where you are converting something to an **int**. Debugging in PHP is a mess.

Comment: You could intall xdebug on the server and e.g. netbeans as the frontend. see http://docs.php.net/debugger-about and http://netbeans.org/kb/docs/php/debugging.html

Comment: Are you using eval(), or create_function() or closures or similar anywhere within your code?

Comment: @Maerlyn It's set like this: auto_append_file =   ... so not file is "attached"

Comment: @Mark Baker No, I don't. I guess it has something todo with __construct, __destruct or __toString (but here I just return '')

Comment: @VolkerK: I only tried XDebug once, and hated it. So if I re-enable it, what should I look for then?

Comment: @Jules: I only create a database connection like $obj_db = new PDO(). After that I only do simple queries for SESSION handling. So only simple select, update, delete statements. I don't use the object for anything else then $obj_db->query().

Comment: You do need breakpoints. Then step through your code until the notice appears. So you can isolate/narrow down the source.

Comment: Look for the lines where you are instantiating objects of class PDOStatement and go further down to see if you are assigning the object or echoing out the object or casting it to an int.

Comment: @mario: Is there a way to have automagically breakpoints for each line in XDebug, like register_tick_function ?

Comment: @Srisa: I only instantiate the object once. Only use it few times for session handling and do not cast or echo it.

Comment: There's an option to hold (like a breakpoint) on script startup. Do you use session.auto_start and register the handler via php.ini/htaccess? That _could_ (warning: wild guess) explain why you get an unknwon source/line number.

Comment: @VolkerK: I got XDebug running (again). But it does not break on breakpoints nor even on first line, which I set as option (But that might be a problem of this sh*t Eclipse M5). I have session_start() in index.php, I do not use anything in php.ini or .htaccess changing "normal" php behavior. Only thing I do is using session_set_save_handler to use databaseD sessions calling the PDO class there.

Comment: @djot PDO is different from PDOStatement. You have only one instance of PDO, but I believe you have more than one PDOStatement objects and the notice is specifically about the PDOStatement.

Comment: @Srisa: No, I only have this single one in the session handling class. I did not use PDO before, the only database executing part that I changed was the session class. I searched all files for PDO anyway and still have only this one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally, I found my own answer to my very own problem:

```
// doing PDO-sql, inserting session data, I ran into my problem.
$this->db_connection = new PDO(...);
$sql_query = "INSERT INTO ".$this->session_db_table." (...) VALUES (...)";
$sql_result = $this->db_connection->query($sql_query);

// This is the line (ideally named "0") from the notice:
return $sql_result;
```

`return $sql_result` is throwing this notice:

"Notice: Object of class PDOStatement could not be converted to int in Unknown on line 0"

`$sql_result` is an `object`; return format expected seems to be `boolean`.

So I removed this `return` and the notice is now gone.

Comment: Still, this does not answer your original question about how to find such places in general. I don't even know the file – it's "Unknown"... :\

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue a while a go and fixed by restarting (w)AMP.

My only guess would be that the extensions didn't load properly.

In my case, I was getting:

> MongoDB\Model\BSONDocument::getiterator in Unknown on line 0