# php memory exhausted on file upload even though file is small

Tags: php, memory, upload

I have a image uploader that uploads base64 image data off HTML5 canvas.

This works on all images I've tried (over 200) except for one image when it logs

```
PHP Fatal error:  Allowed memory size of 33554432 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 8457492 bytes) in Unknown on line 0
```

This happens only with one image (IMG_2613.jpg 1600x1200 image/jpeg 6343099 bytes).
When uploadling this image the post data is:

```
file_name:img_2613.jpg
id:55488
size:large
image_data:data:image/jpeg;base64,/9j/4dy3RXhpZg....
```

Also the error states that it tried to allocate less than the allowed memory

```
<?php 


$root = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'];

$filteredData=substr($_POST['image_data'], strpos($_POST['image_data'], ",")+1);

$unencodedData=base64_decode($filteredData);

if ( !file_exists($root.'/_uploads/'.$_POST['id'].'/') ){
    mkdir($root.'/_uploads/'.$_POST['id'].'/', 0777, true);
}

if ( !file_exists($root.'/_uploads/'.$_POST['id'].'/'.$_POST['size'].'/') ){
    mkdir($root.'/_uploads/'.$_POST['id'].'/'.$_POST['size'].'/', 0777, true);
}

saveFile(0,$root,$unencodedData);



function saveFile($i,$root,$data){
    if ($i == 0){
        $rand = '';
    } else {
        $rand = $i.'_';
    }

    $saveLocation = '/_uploads/'.$_POST['id'].'/'.$_POST['size'].'/'.$rand.$_POST['file_name'];

    if ( file_exists($root.$saveLocation) ){
        saveFile($i+1,$root,$data);
    } else {
        file_put_contents($root.$saveLocation, $data );
        echo $saveLocation;
    }


}


?>
```

Are there any things I should try out? What might be causing this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Modifying the php.ini file did the trick.

```
memory_limit = 128M
```

I assume that even though max post size was the same as memory limit once uploaded it took more memory than the actualy image size. And it failed with a 500 response because it exhausted memory before it even started. That explains error on line 0.

Answer (score 1):

You have recursion in your function. Inside saveFile there is another saveFile. If you comment out saveFile call inside saveFile function, you will see, that you wont get memory exhaustion anymore.

You see, if file exists, then you will try to save file again, which calls the loop all over again. You have a fault in ur logic, i believe.

Comment: Tried to comment the line out and see if it works. It still doesn't. Also there is no existing file and the function isn't repeated in this case if left uncommented out. What it does is if there is a image with that name exists it adds #_ to the image name like '#_name.jpg' where # goes as much up as it needs to work. This function works perfectly with all other images I've uploaded using this script. Any other ideas?

Comment: You could try echoing out the names of the file. and put in a if statment: if($i > 20) exit;

Comment: The error is 'PHP Fatal error:  Allowed memory size of 33554432 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 8457492 bytes) in Unknown on line 0'. It doesn't even read through the file - line 0. Also the file is Unknown as you can see. The error happens when I do a ajax call on the file I showed in the question and chrome returns a 500 error on that ajax call.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9076899/notice-unknown-on-line-0-how-to-find-correct-line-its-not-line-0
Look at this thread. I suggest you try commenting out lines 1 by 1 to find the actual line that causes problems. Or just install XDEBUG and set some breakpoints.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/61074/discussion-between-matthew-abrman-and-lauri-orgla).